# How to determine average volume of an audio file using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, audio, volume, decibel

I want to compare the average volume, in dB, of two audio files for an iPhone application I'm working on for school. I'm working in Xcode, Objective-C.

After some research I found "averagePowerForChannel:" in the AVFoundation Framework, but I can't figure out how it works. Here's some of the code:

```
NSString *stringPath = [NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:wavname ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
avPlayer = [[AVaudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfUrl:url error:nil];
[avPlayer play];
```

The code above plays a .wav file with the name 'wavname'. How do I go about determining its average volume?

```
[avPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0];
```

If I simply add te code above, it'll return -160.000. Which, I guess, is the volume level at the start of the audio file.

How do I use this correctly? Because, at the moment, I'm not seeing why it is called "averagePower", as it only seems to check the volume at one point in time.

Comment: "To obtain a current average power value, you must call the `updateMeters` method before calling this method" - have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your response @moonwave99. I added:

`[avPlayer updateMeter];`

But, it still returns -160.000. I guess I could create a loop, check the value at an interval and calculate an average volume. But, why is it called averagePower, when I need to do that myself?

Comment: To answer my own question:

A volume measurement is always a average. Because, you need multiple sample values to determine a volume.

Answer (score 0):

`averagePowerForChannel:` just returns the average power for the playing or record channel. iow, it's not very useful for analyzing an entire file. the method's useful for current meter values (as one example).

to analyze the file, read all of its sample data (e.g. using ExtAudioFile APIs) calculating its [quadratic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) (for RMS).

Comment: Thank you for your response @justin! (:

I've found the Extended Audio File Services Reference and expect to find some useful things over there! :)

Comment: @RoelfMik you're welcome. also have a look at sample code which uses `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL` for a starting point at reading the sample data.